# EmberJS and custom endpoints urls

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working with EmberJS version 2.14.2 for frontend and I have Rails API backend.
I want to get some data from backend but auto-generated url is different from my API endpoint.

the difference is: emberJS generates /admins/api/v1/domains but my endpoint is actually /admins/api/v1/domains.json

how can I achive this in EmberJS? how can i define a totally different endpoint for some models?

my adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:4000',
  namespace: 'admins/api/v1',
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  headers: Ember.computed('session.access_token', function() {
    return {
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.get('session.access_token')
    };
  })
});
```

my model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  host: DS.attr(), 
  layout: DS.attr(), 
  token: DS.attr(), 
  created_at: DS.attr(), 
  updated_at: DS.attr()
});
```

Is it possible to define a custom endpoint in EmberJS? I really checked the documentation and there is nothing there.

Plz halp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few different options here. You can override each of the different URL-building methods to always append `.json`, or you can override the adapter's `buildURL` method, call `this._super(...arguments)`, and append `.json` to the resulting URL:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function() {
    const url = this._super(...arguments);
    return `${url}.json`;
  }
});
```

However, Rails does content negotiation based on the header that is being sent too. This means that you won't have to append `.json` to your URL's at all.

Ember Data with the JSONAPIAdapter will send the JSON API header `application/vnd.api+json`, not the regular `application/json` that Rails expects to do its content negotiation. You can add that header to Rails through an initializer that does `Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.api+json', :json`. That tells Rails that when a request comes in with that header, it should interpret it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can define different adapters for each model in your app. Simply create an adapter that shares the model name using 'ember new adapter modelname'.  If a model does not have its own adapter, it will use whatever is in the application adapter.

Take a read through the Customizing Adapters section of the Guides. It describes this feature and more info that you will probably need: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/customizing-adapters/